# Grub rescue mod is not letting boot start

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10

During window installation , I deleted Linux partition and when I restarted now  grub rescue >  mode is not disappearing and not starting boot

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a startup repair with a Windows install cd, or reinstall grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: No startup repair appearing after usb insert :( . Usb is working fine on other laptops .

Comment: How did you make the usb?